# Variable intervals from system of inequalities

Tags: matrices, inequality

I have this system of inequalities:

[image: System of inequalities]

and I need to find possible intervals of `i` and `j`.

Looking at the graph output from Wolfram Alpha:

[image: Inequalities graph]

what I'm looking for is result:

[image: Inequalities result]

Is there a simple way to calculate this without looking at graph?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\1&0\\0&-1\\1&-1\\-2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}i\\j\end{pmatrix}<\begin{pmatrix}20\\20\\10\\0\\20\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-i\\i\\-j\\i-j\\-2i+j\end{pmatrix}<\begin{pmatrix}20\\20\\10\\0\\20\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-i<20\\i<20\\-j<10\\i<j\\-2i+j<20\end{pmatrix}$$
Can you solve them?

Answer (score 0):

The system is actually not too complicated. If you multiply them out you should get

-i < 20

i < 20

-j < 10

i-j < 0

-2i + j < 20

From the 2nd inequality, we have our desired upper bound for i. For the lower bound of -15, combine j > -10 and -2i + j < 20.

The 3rd inequality gives us our desired lower bound for j. As for the upper bound of 60, combine i < 20 and -2i+j < 20.